# Given-When-Then scenarios for Webservice calls

Tags: web-services, bdd, specflow

We are using Specflow for automating our regression suite but now we would like to take it to a next level of automating our webservices.

Using the Gherkin “Gven-When-Then”, how can I use / write the webservices calls.

For e.g : How do I write my given - when - then for the below request?

```
<ns:request>
    <ns1:ServiceAuthenticationRequest>
        <ns1:Password>?</ns1:Password>
        <ns1:Station>?</ns1:Station>
        <ns1:UserName>?</ns1:UserName>
    </ns1:ServiceAuthenticationRequest>
    …
</ns:request>
```

Comment: Answered, hope it helps; voting to close your other question as it's a duplicate of this one and this is better phrased IMO (scenarios being preferred to tests; given-when-then being a subset of Gherkin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gherkin tests for webservice calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442589/gherkin-tests-for-webservice-calls)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're writing webservice code itself, the behaviour of a generic webservice probably isn't that interesting.

What does your webservice do?

1) Can you give me an example?

2) Is there any situation in which your webservice would behave differently to that?

If you can answer those questions, you'll probably have a better idea of what to use as your first, and then second, scenario. The situations in which the webservice behaves differently are the contexts (givens); what you get as a result of those contexts will be the outcomes (thens). Calling the webservice will be your event. If your webservice has different capabilities, you'll probably have different events for each one.

As with anything related to BDD, have a conversation with someone and see if you can give them some examples of what you're thinking / ask them for some examples if they're more knowledgeable than you are.